# UV Projection influence?

Tags: mesh, uv, modifiers

I want to make 1 face of an object be the only thing that is affected by the UV Projection modifier

[image]

I tried recreating this but I can only do it by separating the face and having it as an individual object

[image]

I have read that I can use more materials and more UV maps to achieve this in the same object, but doing it that way would create confusion and make things more complicated since this will be used in a rig and that rig will be used multiple times in several scenes, I will also need to change the image texture a lot and doing it with more materials and UVs will take more steps

I believe it's possible with some sort of trick because one guy did it, I tried contacting him but he never responds, it's not impossible

Here's the blend file of a comparison with both test and result objects

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason, you use the UV project modifier and not do it in edit mode with seams and unwrap? regardless, if you want to di it using the modifier i would suggest you split it like before, then apply the modifier to all your separate parts so its gone, and then join everything.

Comment: The reason I'm using the modifier is for the face's UV to not deform, in Minecraft animation beacuse the textures are too small, when you move a vertice it streches all the pixels, so by doing it with this modifier it won't deform the UV's

Comment: You should pack the needed textures in your file (menu "file>External data>Automatically pack into .blend". Above that, what is not clear in the question is either the final result is to be used in Blender or Minecraft? If it is Minecraft, surely you'll bake all finally? Another aspect: have you tried to use multiple projectors in the same UV project modifier?

Comment: oops forgot to pack textures, the final result is for cycles blender, I'll also add an example rig of what it should be like

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any other limits you'd like to impose?  Limiting the influence of a UV project modifier is doable with 1 object, 1 material, 2 UV maps.  But odds are good that you don't actually need a UV project modifier to do what it is that you're doing.  If you're rendering in Blender, then Minecraft texturing limitations don't apply; if you're rendering in Minecraft, your export function is probably just writing your UV Project modifier to UV anyways.

Comment: @Nathan you could try disecting the Example Rig to understand my question better, the way it works is that it has an empty controlling the face UV and it's parented to the head bone so the face texture doesn't deform

Comment: I have looked at the file, but I didn't notice the rig.  (I did notice that there are more than three objects and I could only find one material.)  On looking again, I notice no deformation (I believe you're referring to texture warping?) after applying the UV project modifier on the two objects I could find that use it, so if there's an issue with rendering in Blender without using a UV project modifier, I'm afraid I don't see it.

Comment: @Nathan I tried explaining a bit more of the result, check Edit 3, and thanks for helping on this so far :)

Comment: Well, it's still not useful, because it doesn't show me where to look.  I've looked all over your model for what your pixellated image is supposed to represent, so that I can see it in action, but there is absolutely nothing green in your file.  Now, what you're demonstrating on that picture could be done with a UV warp modifier instead of a UV project modifier, and UV warp modifiers can be vertex group limited, unlike UV project modifiers.  That might be a way to go for you.

Comment: @Nathan I made it work with the UV Warp thanks!, now if you could write an answer so you can get the reputation points?

Comment: I don't care about rep, and I don't have an answer that meets the question as written (using UV Project with only 1 UV map.)

Comment: @Nathan oh ok, anyway, thanks for helping :D

Comment: @Nathan so umm... I assumed it would work until I did some testing... the UVs are still getting deformed with the warp modifier, any ideas?

Comment: Since I never was able to see the problem in the model you uploaded, I couldn't tell you.  If you prepare a different model, one that clearly demonstrates the issue, with as few objects as possible (pose it so it looks bad, get rid of everything that doesn't matter), then get my attention, I'll look at it.  Or your other option is to ask a new question, "How can I limit my UV Project modifier using only 2 UV maps," because the reality is, that solution is no more difficult or tedious than a solution involving assigning verts to vert groups.

Comment: I'll make sure to simplify it, time to edit the question

Comment: @Nathan There!, I think I made it simple enough to understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll get to an answer in a second.

We've been back and forth in comments, and no, your latest .blend clarifies nothing.  Presumably, your object on the viewer's left demonstrates the need for the UV project modifier, but if you alt-g reset the bone and apply the UV project modifier, then move it back into position, it behaves exactly the same as it would with the active UV Project modifier.  So, yeah, I still have no idea about why this needs to occur.

Now, I'll give you an answer, but it's not the answer you're looking for, because I'll instead tell you how to limit a UV project modifier using only 2 UV maps, no extra objects (beyond the required projector and projectee), no extra materials.  Why ignore your explicit limits?  Because I still haven't heard any reason why your limits are important to your output, and because the reality is, doing it with 2 UV maps is extraordinarily simple and easy to implement.  Maybe you've been doing it a different way and think it's too complicated; it's not, and I'll show you.

Let's start with a single object and a single UV map.  Unbelievably, yours is already perfect...

[image]

Why is it perfect?  Because the faces that you want to use your UV projector modifier on are already out of bounds: all of the faces have U coordinates <0.  This is important as we'll see.

Now let's make another UV map.

[image]

So ugly!  But the actual content of this UV map doesn't even matter.  Do anything you want here.  Arrange your UVs into NWA lyrics as an easter egg, it's cool.  I just reset the whole thing to demonstrate that it doesn't matter.  In practice, it's just going to be a copy of your first UV map, since that's what you get when you hit the + button for a new UV map and don't do any other work, because you don't need to.

Time for the modifier.  This is the exact same modifier you have on your .blend, except it uses our second UV map.  I'll give you a picture, but you already know how it works.  You might want to notice that I'm back on UV0, and so I've got an ugly white face where my beautiful pixelly face ought to be.

[image]

Now, we don't need any additional materials, but we do need to edit our existing material.  I'm doing some hacky things here, just to save us some nodes, and I'll explain them; you can always feel free to do it the "right" way instead, and I can explain that too.  Here's our nodes.

[image]

So, first, notice the face is now there; it wasn't before.  This is working.  It's working in rendered preview too, but the lighting's poor, so I used mat preview instead.

Now, let's explain what I'm doing.  I'm getting two different UV coords.  And then I'm mixing between them on the basis of whether the first UV coords are out of bounds.  More particularly, on whether the U coordinate is less than 0.  So what I'm doing is using UV0 to code for whether or not my face should get affected by the UV project modifier.

The hacks are:

1) I'm just sending UV vector to a math node.  The math node ends up operating on the first element of the vector only, which is U.  That's why it works.  More professional would be to run this through a separate XYZ node first.

2) I'm using a Mix RGB node to blend between the UV.  Mix RGB doesn't actually know whether it's getting a vector or a color, all it does is mix.  Here, it does fine.  We could separate XYZ, multiply each channel by fac or 1 - fac, then add them, which would be more professional, but harder to fit into a screenshot, and Mix RGB works fine.

What do I end up with?  A single object where the OOB status of faces on UV0 determines whether or not we use UV1.  Add the armature modifier and you're good to go.

See?  Not so complicated.

Comment: It worked... sometimes I block myself to one idea on how to do things, I make easy things complicated, I'm sorry if I got to be annoying at one point for not listening to other options, but I appreciate that you got the patience to help me, thank you

Comment: It's cool.  It's just better to focus on the desired outcome, and the undesired side effects of things you've tried, than to get too locked into, "It has to be done via x method."